# XSLT tree structure based on item numbers

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, tree, jstree

I have a problem with my XSLT-Stylesheet. I have a XML document with multiple assemblys. Each assembly has a unique item number. An assembly can contain other assemblys as positions, but the XML document has a flat structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<PartsCatalog Version="1.0">
<Description><![CDATA[asdsadasdadad       ]]></Description>
<Assembly Item="0000            " Plate="          " Class="                ">
<Description Lang=" DE"><![CDATA[Main assembly]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" EN"><![CDATA[Main assembly]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" FR"><![CDATA[Main assembly]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" IT"><![CDATA[Main assembly]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" RU"><![CDATA[Main assembly]]></Description>
<Position PositionNumber="  10" Item="9284424         " Plate="000020    " Class="                ">
    <Quantity Unit="st ">        1,0000</Quantity>
    <Serie From="          " To="          "></Serie>
    <Characteristic><![CDATA[                              ]]></Characteristic>
    <SparePartFlag><![CDATA[00]]></SparePartFlag>
    <Description Lang=" DE"><![CDATA[aaaaaa            ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" EN"><![CDATA[aaaaaa            ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" FR"><![CDATA[aaaaaa            ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" IT"><![CDATA[aaaaaa            ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" RU"><![CDATA[                              ]]></Description>
</Position>
<Position PositionNumber="  20" Item="9207826         " Plate="104300    " Class="                ">
    <Quantity Unit="st ">        1,0000</Quantity>
    <Serie From="          " To="          "></Serie>
    <Characteristic><![CDATA[10.00-20 PR16                 ]]></Characteristic>
    <SparePartFlag><![CDATA[00]]></SparePartFlag>
    <Description Lang=" DE"><![CDATA[8 GELAENDEREIFEN              ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" EN"><![CDATA[8 OFFROAD TIRES               ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" FR"><![CDATA[8 PNEUS TOUT-TERRAIN          ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" IT"><![CDATA[8 PNEUMATICI FUORI STRADA     ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" RU"><![CDATA[                              ]]></Description>
</Position>
<Position PositionNumber="  30" Item="9178702         " Plate="104280    " Class="                ">
    <Quantity Unit="st ">        1,0000</Quantity>
    <Serie From="          " To="          "></Serie>
    <Characteristic><![CDATA[MH 3                          ]]></Characteristic>
    <SparePartFlag><![CDATA[00]]></SparePartFlag>
    <Description Lang=" DE"><![CDATA[ZWISCHENRING                  ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" EN"><![CDATA[INTERMEDIATE RING             ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" FR"><![CDATA[ENTRETOISE                    ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" IT"><![CDATA[ANELLO DISTANZIATORE          ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" RU"><![CDATA[ÏÐÎÊËÀÄÎ×ÍÎÅ ÊÎËÜÖÎ           ]]></Description>
</Position>
<Assembly Item="9284424         " Plate="000020    " Class="11100301        ">
<Description Lang=" DE"><![CDATA[aaaaa            ]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" EN"><![CDATA[aaaaa            ]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" FR"><![CDATA[aaaaa            ]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" IT"><![CDATA[aaaaa            ]]></Description>
<Description Lang=" RU"><![CDATA[                              ]]></Description>
<Image PositionFrom="   0">187994</Image>
<Position PositionNumber=" 100" Item="9284426         " Plate="201000    " Class="110000          ">
    <Quantity Unit="st ">        1,0000</Quantity>
    <Serie From="          " To="          "></Serie>
    <Characteristic><![CDATA[                              ]]></Characteristic>
    <SparePartFlag><![CDATA[20]]></SparePartFlag>
    <Description Lang=" DE"><![CDATA[OBERWAGEN                     ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" EN"><![CDATA[UPPERCARRIAGE                 ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" FR"><![CDATA[TOURELLE                      ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" IT"><![CDATA[TORRETTA                      ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" RU"><![CDATA[ÏÎÂÎÐÎÒÍÀß ÏËÀÒÔÎÐÌÀ          ]]></Description>
</Position>
<Position PositionNumber=" 200" Item="9281013         " Plate="102000    " Class="110000          ">
    <Quantity Unit="st ">        1,0000</Quantity>
    <Serie From="          " To="          "></Serie>
    <Characteristic><![CDATA[                              ]]></Characteristic>
    <SparePartFlag><![CDATA[20]]></SparePartFlag>
    <Description Lang=" DE"><![CDATA[UNTERWAGEN 2PKT.              ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" EN"><![CDATA[UNDERCARRIAGE 2PTS.           ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" FR"><![CDATA[CHASSIS 2PTS.                 ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" IT"><![CDATA[CARRO 2STAB.                  ]]></Description>
    <Description Lang=" RU"><![CDATA[                              ]]></Description>
</Position>
</Assembly>
```

The only way to identify a sub assembly is the item number.
I want to display the XML as a tree structure using the [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) jquery plugin.
Therefore I need a HTML output like this:

```
<div id="jsTree">
 <ul>
  <li>0001 | Main assembly
    <ul>
      <li>1111 | Sub assembly 1</li>
      <li>2222 | Sub assembly 2</li>
      <li>3333 | Sub assembly 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried to use many answers of questions similar to my problem so far, but nothing worked. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Greetings
B0R0H

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I've posted a more detailed version of the code below.

Comment: You should not add a new answer, edit the question instead.

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm pretty new on this website. :)
I will delete the post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you help! :) I've just found the solution for the problem. I've posted it for other people who have (maybe) a similar problem. This one worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:variable name="lang-all" select="distinct-values(//Description/@Lang)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$lang-all">
        <xsl:variable name="lang" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$doc">
            <xsl:variable name="filename_index" select="concat('output/',$lang,'/','index','.html')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="jstree">
                <xsl:call-template name="build-list">
                    <xsl:with-param name="lang" select="$lang" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="PartsCatalog/Assembly[1]" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$filename_index"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="{$filename_index}">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                        <title>ETK</title>
                        <script src="../0jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
                        <script src="../0jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js"/>
                        <script src="../0dropdown/jquery.easydropdown.min.js"/>
                        <script src="../0jstree/dist/jstree.min.js"/>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../0jquery/jquery-ui-themes-1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../0jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../0dropdown/themes/easydropdown.css" type="text/css"/>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../0css/style.css"  type="text/css"/>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div class="head">
                            <div class="innertube_head">
                                <h1>ETK</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <div class="jstree_header">
                                <xsl:value-of select="PartsCatalog/Description"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="innertube_left" id="jstree">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$jstree" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="center">
                            <div class="center_top"/>
                            <div class="center_bottom"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <div class="3d_frame"></div>
                            <div class="innertube_right">
                                    <select id="countries" class="dropdown">
                                        <option value="#">Change language</option>
                                        <option value="../{$lang-all[1]}/index.html">german</option>
                                        <option value="../{$lang-all[2]}/index.html">english</option>
                                        <option value="../{$lang-all[3]}/index.html">french</option>
                                        <option value="../{$lang-all[4]}/index.html">italian</option>
                                        <option value="../{$lang-all[5]}/index.html">russian</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <script>
                                        $('#countries').bind('change', function () {

                                            var url = $(this).val();

                                            if (url != '') {
                                                window.location = url;
                                            }
                                            return false;
                                        });
                                    </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                          $(function () {
                            // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
                            $('#jstree').jstree();

                            // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
                            $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
                              console.log(data.selected);
                            });

                            // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
                            $('button').on('click', function () {
                              $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
                              $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
                              $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
                            });
                          });
                        </script>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Assembly">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Position"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Position">
    <xsl:param name="lang"/>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@PositionNumber)"/>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Description[@Lang=$lang])"/>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@Item)"/>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Quantity)"/>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Quantity/@Unit)"/>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="build-list">
<xsl:param name="node"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="lang"></xsl:param>
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/Position">
            <xsl:variable name="item" select="@Item" />
            <xsl:if test="count(//Assembly[@Item = $item]) != 0">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@Item)"/> | <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Description[@Lang=$lang])"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="build-list">
                        <xsl:with-param name="node" select="//Assembly[@Item = $item]" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="lang" select="$lang" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(//Assembly[@Item = $item]) = 0">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@Item)"/> | <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Description[@Lang=$lang])"/></li>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a **key** so that each assembly can apply templates (recursively) to its components:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kAssy" match="Assembly" use="@Item" />

<xsl:template match="/PartsCatalog">
<div id="jsTree">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Assembly[Description='Main assembly']"/>
    </ul>
</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Assembly">
<li>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Item"/>
    <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mySubs" select="key('kAssy', Position/@Item)" />
    <xsl:if test="$mySubs">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$mySubs"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @B0R0H If your problem is solved, please close the question by accepting one of the answers given - or (if none of the answers helped) write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is that you need to do a top-down recursive descent through the data using xsl:apply-templates in the normal way, but with one exception: instead of processing the physical children of a node in the XML tree, you need to process its logical children. So instead of writing

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
```

as you normally would, you write

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Assembly[@Item = current()/Position/@Item]"/>
```

and then the next stage is that you can optimize this using keys, as described by michael.hor257k (not necessary if you're using a processor like Saxon-EE that does the optimization automatically).