# XSLT nested selects

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am relatively new to xslt I need to select the comments elements from according to which post using pid of the current post

The part XSLT I am having problem with

```
<xsl:for-each select="posts/post">
    <div class="post">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="ptitle"/></h3>
        <span><xsl:value-of select="ptext"/></span>
        <xsl:variable name="pid" select="@pid" />
        <!-- Here i need to select the comment according to the pid -->
    </div>
    <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

The XML code

```
    <posts>
         <post pid="p2">
            <ptitle>APPLICATIONS OF THE FUTURE</ptitle>
            <pfeatureimage>aig.jpg</pfeatureimage>
            <ptext xml:lang="en">just text </ptext>
            <pdate>25062013</pdate>
            <pimg>future.jpg</pimg>
            <pimg>future.jpg</pimg>
            <pimg>future.jpg</pimg>
            <pauthorid>a3</pauthorid>
        </post>
    </posts>

    <comments>
        <comment cid="c1">
            <pid>p2</pid>
            <uid>u2</uid>
            <ctext>other t</ctext>
            <likes>5</likes>
            <dislikes>1</dislikes>
        </comment>
                <comment cid="c2">
            <pid>p3</pid>
            <uid>u2</uid>
            <ctext>bogsg</ctext>
            <likes>5</likes>
            <dislikes>1</dislikes>
        </comment>
  </comments>
```

Comment: The XPath expression you need is this: `//comments/comment[pid=current()/@pid]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to approach any cross-referencing problem like this in XSLT is to use a [*key*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key).  You put the key definition at the top-level of your stylesheet (outside any templates):

```
<xsl:key name="commentsByPid" match="comment" use="pid" />
```

The `match` expression determines which nodes to look at, and the `use` is a path that is evaluated relative to each matched node to determine the key value (so in this case it will take the string value of the `pid` element inside each matched `comment`).

With this key definition you can efficiently look up all the comments that match the current post's `pid` attribute using the `key` function:

```
<xsl:for-each select="posts/post">
    <div class="post">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="ptitle"/></h3>
        <span><xsl:value-of select="ptext"/></span>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('commentsByPid', @pid)">
            <!-- do whatever you need with the <comment> here -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: *"The way to approach any cross-referencing problem like this in XSLT is to use a key"* That's what I think, too (+1), but apparently not everyone agrees: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21230772/3016153

Comment: I prefer to think of the key as a way of optimizing a join, but I've no problem with people who prefer to implement every join with a key: it's a reasonable bet that it's the best solution most of the time.

Comment: @MichaelKay To me the optimized performance is a bonus; I find keys more readable and maintainable. But then I could be biased from dealing with relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

For a single comment, replace your variable definition

```
<xsl:variable name="pid" select="@pid" />
```

by

```
<xsl:value-of select="//comments/comment[pid=current()/@pid]/ctext" />
```

If you have multiple comments, you can try

```
<xsl:variable name="pid" select="@pid" />
<xsl:for-each select="//comments/comment[pid=$pid]">
    <xsl:value-of select="ctext" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The answer from Ian is much better. Didn't know that before.